# How to set a postman environment variable's value to another variable's?

Tags: postman

So let's say I have a list of environment variables and their values. Now I want to add another variable, but also set its value as one of the existing variables' value.

Here is an example; let's say I need to keep track of hex colors. Then I'd have variables like

```
VARIABLE | INITIAL VALUE | CURRENT VALUE
Red      |               | #ff0000
Green    |               | #00ff00
Blue     |               | #0000ff
```

and possibly a few more.

Now how would I add a default color `Color` variable where I set it to one of the existing variables instead of copy pasting their values? I still need the individual color variables, but also would be nice to have a default variable I can change it's value once in a while to one of the exiting variables.

In reality I have bunch of GUIDs and it's easy to mess them copy pasting them multiple times. So I want to define them just once and reuse these variables.

Comment: Have you tried adding the default one and adding its value as something dynamic like `{{Red}}` or something else that's going to be changing?

Comment: Yes that works, I've posted that as a self answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply setting the default color to one of the defined variables seems to work. The following sets the `Default` variable to `Red`'s value of `#ff0000`

```
VARIABLE | INITIAL VALUE | CURRENT VALUE
Red      |               | #ff0000
Default  |               | {{Red}}
```